# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'templates' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, themes

i'm using WordPress and I use the template divi (it's like a drag and drop theme, really easy to use. But now there is an error in my developer console and I don't understand it!), help is appreciated:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'templates' of null
    at Object.success (builder.js?ver=3.0.98:152)
    at i (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.2:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.2:2)
    at y (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.2:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.2:4)

success @   builder.js?ver=3.0.98:152
i   @   load-scripts.php?c=1…lupload&ver=4.9.2:2
fireWith    @   load-scripts.php?c=1…lupload&ver=4.9.2:2
y   @   load-scripts.php?c=1…lupload&ver=4.9.2:4
c   @   load-scripts.php?c=1…lupload&ver=4.9.2:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)     
send    @   load-scripts.php?c=1…lupload&ver=4.9.2:4
ajax    @   load-scripts.php?c=1…lupload&ver=4.9.2:4
et_builder_load_backbone_templates  @   builder.js?ver=3.0.98:137
(anonymous) @   builder.js?ver=3.0.98:321
(anonymous) @   builder.js?ver=3.0.98:18181
```

If I click on the builder.js file, this line is causing the error..

```
  if ( !_.isUndefined(data.templates) && data.templates.length ) {
                        _.each( data.templates, function( single_module ) {
                            template = et_pb_template_rebuild(single_module['template'], data.unique);
                            try {
                                localStorage.setItem( et_ls_prefix + single_module['slug'], LZString.compressToUTF16( template ) );
                            } catch(e) {
                                // do not use localStorage if it full or any other error occurs

                                et_builder_maybe_clear_localstorage();
                            } etcetra... etcetra..
```

I copy and pasted lot's of code now because maybe you can get more information out of it:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: et_pb_options.ajaxurl,
                    data: {
                        action : 'et_pb_increase_memory_limit',
                        et_admin_load_nonce : et_pb_options.et_admin_load_nonce
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        if ( ! _.isUndefined( data.success ) ) {
                            $this_button.addClass( 'et_builder_modal_action_button_success' ).text( et_pb_options.memory_limit_increased );
                        } else {
                            $this_button.addClass( 'et_builder_modal_action_button_fail' ).prop( 'disabled', true ).text( et_pb_options.memory_limit_not_increased );
                        }
                    }
                });
            return false;
        } );

        $( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.et_pb_reload_builder', function() {
            location.reload();

            return false;
        } );

    }

    if ( et_should_load_from_local_storage() ) {
        for ( et_ls_module_index in et_ls_all_modules ) {
            var et_ls_module_slug      = et_ls_all_modules[ et_ls_module_index ],
                et_ls_template_slug    = et_ls_prefix + et_ls_module_slug,
                et_ls_template_content = LZString.decompressFromUTF16( localStorage.getItem( et_ls_template_slug ) );

            // count the processed modules
            processed_modules_count++;

            if ( _.isUndefined( et_ls_template_content ) || _.isNull( et_ls_template_content ) || '' === et_ls_template_content ) {
                missing_modules['missing_modules_array'].push( et_ls_module_slug );
            } else {
                local_storage_buffer += LZString.decompressFromUTF16( localStorage.getItem( et_ls_template_slug ) );
            }

            // perform ajax request if missing_modules_array length equals to the templates amount setting or if all the modules processed and we need to retrieve something
            if ( ! et_is_loading_missing_modules && ( ( missing_modules['missing_modules_array'].length === parseInt( et_pb_options.et_builder_templates_amount ) ) || ( missing_modules['missing_modules_array'].length && ( et_ls_all_modules.length === processed_modules_count ) ) ) ) {
                et_is_loading_missing_modules = true;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: et_pb_options.ajaxurl,
                    data: {
                        action : 'et_pb_get_backbone_template',
                        et_post_type : et_pb_options.post_type,
                        et_modules_slugs : JSON.stringify( missing_modules ),
                        et_admin_load_nonce : et_pb_options.et_admin_load_nonce
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        et_is_loading_missing_modules = false;

                        var template;
                        // Backend always returns an array of templates, even for a single module.
                        if ( !_.isUndefined(data.templates) && data.templates.length ) {
                            _.each( data.templates, function( single_module ) {
                                template = et_pb_template_rebuild(single_module['template'], data.unique);
                                try {
                                    localStorage.setItem( et_ls_prefix + single_module['slug'], LZString.compressToUTF16( template ) );
                                } catch(e) {
                                    // do not use localStorage if it full or any other error occurs

                                    et_builder_maybe_clear_localstorage();
                                }

                                $( 'body' ).append( template );
                            } );
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: well that means data is null.....

Comment: Where is data coming from? Can you share that code?

Comment: I mad the code longer... I have no clue where the data is coming from??? How can I figure that out.. It's a divi theme from wordpress...